# Network days and IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am looking for a formula to count the business days (excluding public holidays) between two dates. Which I have a formula for, the issue is when the second column is blank. If it is blank, I would like it to calculate is as if the blank is today. I have googled but I have been unable to find a formula that includes the IF statement (its one or the other)

My current formula is

```
=((NETWORKDAYS(K2,L2,Sheet2!O3:O36)-1)
```

Sheet 2 is where I have the public holidays

The above formula returns a -30000 number when L column is blank

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current formula works fine then you can use-

```
=NETWORKDAYS(K2,IF(L2="",TODAY(),L2),Sheet2!O3:O36)-1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It worked with an additional bracket at the end.                                   
=((NETWORKDAYS(K2,IF(L2="",TODAY(),L2),Sheet2!O3:O36)-1))

Comment: @Katrina why have two extra brackets at the start? which then requires two closing at the end?

Comment: @Katrina You do not need brackets at starting and ending.